# How to access locale and global in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, locale

How do I access "locale" and "global" without using the syntax

```
 using namespace std
```

Its the following syntax I have problem with

```
 #include <locale>

 locale::global(locale("swedish"));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`locale` lives in the `std` namespace:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("swedish"));
```